# rotation of spherical coordinate system

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems

If I rotate the coordinate system by spherical angles θ and ϕ, and the vector in the new system is v'=(x′,y′,z′), what is its coordinate (x,y,z) in the original coordinate system? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not immediately clear what is your coordinate system, and how you define rotations. Let's assume that you have first a rotation around $x$ axis by angle $\theta$, then a rotation around $z$ axis by angle $\phi$. You can then write $$\textrm v'=R_z(\phi)R_x(\theta)\textrm v$$
Note the order of rotations in the above equation. You can find the matrix representation of this rotation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) for example.

Then just multiplying with the inverses, in reverse order, you get
$$R_x^{-1}(\theta)R_z^{-1}(\phi)\textrm v'=R_x^{-1}(\theta)R_z^{-1}(\phi)R_z(\phi)R_x(\theta)\textrm v=\textrm v$$

Note that the inverse of the simple rotation matrices can be written as the transpose or rotation by negative angle:
$R^{-1}(\alpha)=R^T(\alpha)=R(-\alpha)$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! It helps! I just have one more question about the order of rotations. The new coordinate system is created as following: there is a point on the sphere with coordinate (θ, ϕ); The line passing through the origin and this point is my new z axis (the orientation of x and y axes don't matter). In this case, should I first rotate around x axis by angle θ, or rotate aroung z axis by angle ϕ?

Comment: You need to rotate first around your new $z$ axis by $-\phi$. That way your $x'$ axis rotates first to $x$.

Comment: I see, thank you a lot!